# How Can I Get My Alexa Skill To Send Gmails When The User Makes Certain Requests?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, nodemailer, oauth2-playground

I am building an Alexa Skill that submits orders into a database, and I would like it also to email the user that the order was sent along with the items ordered. I am using JavaScript with NodeMailer in my Lambda function with credentials from Google's OAuth Sandbox.  It works great except the credentials have a time limit on them of about an hour. I am totally new to the Google OAuth sandbox.  I was wondering how I could extend the time that the credentials work indefinitely or should I use an entirely different approach?

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

In your case you should use `RefreshToken`

> **5. Refresh the access token, if necessary.**
>
> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

More in [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).